# Custom directive scope.$watch not being fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying link two datepicker directives I'm passing model to one of directives and I need to run few methods when the value gets changed however when the value changes scope.$watch in linking function does not get fired. I've been trying to solve this issue for the past two days to no avail... anything I throw does not work.. can someone have a look and explain what is wrong?

I've setup a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/VTSElDjniyN8wRwsuT1T?p=preview

Jacvascript code below

UPDATE 21/12/2016 updated plunker link as initial link was incorrect.

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('endDatepicker', function() {
return {
  scope: {
      model: "=",
      endDate: "=",
  },
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-template.html',
  link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch('endDate', function(newValue,oldValue){
          console.log("Watch fired" + scope.endDate)
          scope.dateOptions.minDate = scope.endDate;
      },true)


     scope.popupOpen = false;
      scope.openPopup = function($event) {
          $event.preventDefault();
          $event.stopPropagation();
          scope.popupOpen = true;
      };

      scope.dateOptions = {
        startingDay: 1,
        minDate: moment.utc()._d
      }
      scope.open = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        scope.opened = true;
      };

  }
 };
});
```

Comment: your plunkr and code above dont match.

Comment: try removing the true option at the end of the watch, because as far as I see endDate is not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are passing the `model` to both `directives`, the updates are not reflected in one when one of them changes since the `model` sits on the `directive scope` rather than `parent scope`, instead of watching the model in one directive raise an event when the model changes in one and watch for that event in the second model and do your operation in there:

First directive:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

    elm.bind('blur', function() {
        var currentValue = elm.val();
        scope.$emit('FIRST_DATE_UPDATED', currentValue);
    });
}
```

And in the second directive:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

    scope.$on('FIRST_DATE_UPDATED', function(e, data){
        var newDateValue = data;
        //do your stufdf here
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your inputs. Yes indeed the link was incorrect this was my first question on stack so had my hands a bit shaky :) Yaser thanks for eye opener I realized that my end-datepicker directive was oustide of ng-controller scope so it was sitting in it's own isolated scope... I managed now to get scope.$watch method to work and catch the new value, however I tried your suggestion along side $watch solution to see how I can use it if circumstances arise, but I cannot get it to work. Putting correct link http://plnkr.co/edit/VTSElDjniyN8wRwsuT1T?p=preview